# I want to extract the index containing the corresponding value using filter

Tags: javascript

```
var data = 2021;
console.log(fcltsData);
const result = fcltsData.prvntList.filter(p => p.prctcList.inspcMon.substring(0,4) === data);
```

[image]
[image]

I wanted to get a prvntList whose inspcMon value and data value in prvntList in fcltsData match, so I applied the filter function as follows, but an Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'substring') error occurred. Is there a solution?

The reason I put substring in the filter was to compare only the year of the data like 2021-05. When I run the substring separately, 2021 was successfully imported.

Comment: `substring` returns a string, but you’re comparing it with a number. A comparison with `===` between the two will always be `false`. `prctcList` is an array. Arrays do not have `inspcMon` properties. Familiarize yourself with [how to access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON](/q/11922383/4642212).

Comment: As you advised, I changed the test variable to a string and to access the [0] index to access the nested array, I still get the same error. Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'inspcMon')

Comment: var test = "2021"
        const result = fcltsData.prvntList.filter(p => p.prctcList[0].inspcMon.substring(0,4) === test);

Comment: That is _not_ the same error. Please [edit] your question and provide a [mre] (this means, your _code must be in the question itself, as [formatted text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361/4642212) and [**not** a picture](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4642212)_).